# ios10 doesn't show notification custom action button

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, swift3

I want to display the notification custom action button when my app receives a notification. But nothing happened! Anyone can help me? Thx.

This is my `AppDelegate.swift` code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Register ourselves as a delegate so we can be notified when actions pressed.
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        // Request permission.
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert]) {
            granted, error in
            if granted {
                print("Approval granted to send notifications")
            }
        }

        self.addCategory()

        return true
    }

    func addCategory() {
        // Add action.
        let stopAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "stop", title: "Stop", options: [])
        let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "snooze", title: "Snooze", options: [])

        // Create category.
        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "reminder", actions: [stopAction, snoozeAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
    }
}
```

**UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate**

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationPresentAtForeground"), object: nil)
        completionHandler([.alert])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.I didn't set my notification content category identifier.
The following worked for me:

```
content.categoryIdentifier = "reminder"
```